# Multi-Classing with a Custom Object and Emulating Container Types

Tags: python, methods, subclass

Actual example: so I have a single six-sided die (d6) that I'm going to put with 3 others for a collection of 4 six-sided dice (4d6). I can, of course, roll 1d6 at a time, but I'd rather roll 4d6 at 'the same time'.

So this is my `component.py` module that contains a Component class. That in of itself is basically an empty class (it has a name attribute), so that shouldn't affect the rest of this question:

```
class Die(Component):

    def __init__(self, sides=6, start=1, stop=6):
        super(Die, self).__init__()
        self.sides = sides
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def roll(self):
        die_range = self.stop - self.start + 1
        result = randrange(self.start, self.stop, die_range/self.sides)
        return result
```

I want to be able to eventually write something close to this in a `game.py` script that looks like this:

```
from component import Dice

my_dice = Dice(count=4)
my_dice.append(Dice(count=3, sides=12, stop=12))
print(my_dice.roll())
```

And I'd expect the output to look like:

```
4, 2, 3, 1, 7, 12, 8
```

I'm far **less** concerned about making the output look nice. I can figure that out; I've just given it for the full context.

So here's what I've written for the `Dice` class:

```
class Dice(Die, object):
    def __init__(self, container=None, count=0, **kwargs):
        super(Dice, self).__init__()
        if container is None:
            container = []
        if kwargs is not None:
            for x in range(count):
                container.append(Die(**kwargs))

        self.container = container

    def append(self, item):
        if hasattr(item, 'container'):
            self.container.extend(item.container)
        elif issubclass(item, Die):
            self.container.append(item.container)
        else:
            raise Exception(TypeError)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.container)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.container)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Dice(self.container[key])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.container)

    def roll(self):
        results = []
        for die in self.container:
            results.append(die.roll())
        return results
```

Is this good design? I'm not convinced one way or another that it is.

In case anyone is interested as to the application, I'm building a tabletop game framework, and I want generic classes that other people can subclass easily to make their games more rapidly.

Comment: i think the fact that you append Dice to Dice seems awkward... is this you intention? I would imagine this making sense to be extend rather than appen

Comment: @user3012759, that's a good point. Let me update that method with something better.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, I think, using so close class names as Die as Dice is confusing and error prone. I'd go with Die & DiceSet.

  ```
  class Dice(Die, object):
  ```
- I don't understand what Dice inherit from Die, and does it really need to inherit it?

  ```
  if hasattr(item, 'container'):
      self.container.extend(item.container)
  ```
- looks not reliable, so every object of some class having "container" will be added to Dice container... Would it be better to check if it's subclass of Dice?

  ```
  elif issubclass(item, Die):
      self.container.append(item.container)
  ```
- I think it's some copy-paste typo, since Die shouldn't have any container, so just `append(item)`

  ```
   result = randrange(self.start, self.stop, die_range/self.sides)
  ```
- I am not sure about calculation of step. Step should never be fractional. I think it should be always "1":

  ```
  result = randrange(self.start, self.stop, 1)
  ```
- and number of sides doesn't play the role. You only need it for checking if *start* and *stop* less than *sides*. Of course, you are missing check for *start* less than *stop*. And you can use *sides* for default initialization of *stop* (if it's not given).
- you can store the last result of Die as a private property of Die: initialize it to *start* or to random value in *Die*.`__init__` (up to design), and then save it in *roll*. So you can override representation in Die:

  ```
  def __repr__(self):
       print str(self.last_result)
  ```

and then modify representation of Dice:

```
    def __repr__(self):
         print ','.join(self.container)
```

So you will get a set of numbers when printing Dice object.

Comment: @raiderrobert Does it make sense for you?